# Func<int, int> from conditional expression

Tags: c#

Why we cannot write something like that:

```
Func<int, int> operation = i == 1 
    ? (int a, int b) => a + b 
    : (int a, int b) => a * b;
```

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

Comment: I'm assuming you mean to have a `Func<int, int, int>`. You can get this to compile if you explicitly cast one of the lambda expressions. I assume this has something to do with not being able to implicitly type a lambda, and the ternary checking that both paths share the same type before checking if they are valid to assign to `operation`.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do it, but it's ugly `Func<int, int, int> operation = i == 1 ?(Func<int, int, int>)((int a, int b) => a + b):(int a, int b) => a * b;`

Comment: You are missing many of the int generics you should in fact have this: Func<int, int, int, int> operation = (op, a, b) => (op == 1) ? a + b : a * b;